# Compressing VARCHAR in SQL 2008/12 - not seeing results

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have been experimenting with compression in SQL Server but so far I have not seen the results that I expected.

To test I have created a new table with single `VARCHAR(8000)` column and inserted 100k rows into it. Each row contains about 500 words of text, which using ZIP compression sees over a 90% saving in space.

I am using the command `EXEC sp_estimate_data_compression_savings 'dbo', 'MyTable', NULL, NULL, 'PAGE' ;` to check how much space would be saved using PAGE compression, but it is telling me that there won't be much at all. The results are as follows:

```
object_name schema_name index_id    partition_number    size_with_current_compression_setting(KB)   size_with_requested_compression_setting(KB) sample_size_with_current_compression_setting(KB)    sample_size_with_requested_compression_setting(KB)
MyTable      dbo        0         1                       94048                                                  93440                               40064                                              39808
```

Which is basically no saving at all. Where am I going wrong?

ps. I have tried the same experiment with `NVARCHAR(4000)` column, and compression does show savings there, but I believe this is because the compression forcing use of 1 char instead of two where the data doesn't require 2 chars. It doesn't actually compress the data in a way similar to ZIP would.

Comment: Are you using page or row compression? What is the key on the table? I don't know that 500 words is a good pattern for compression since it is unlikely that you'll get much compression on any given page (compression works on an individual page at a time).

Comment: I tested both PAGE and ROW compression. PAGE was used in the example above. Many words are repeating. If I ZIP a text file containing the 500 sample words there is over 90% compression...

Comment: But many words in a single tuple repeating does not compress well. ZIP has the benefit of being able to compress across *all* tuples.

Comment: @AaronBertrand For the test I used an int as a PK, and also tested with no key. Similar results both times.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I'm not sure I follow. To clarify, the text has many repeating words in both each row (that is, in each VARCHAR cell) and also in across rows. Lets say for example that I novel stored in the database, with a page stored in each row.  Surely this would be a great candidate for compression.

Comment: Also check if your data is actually being stored off-row - compression is not available for values that are stored off-row.

Comment: Quite simply, your data set does not really compress using SQL Servers compression implementation. ZIP is a completely different methodology and is far more efficient in your scenario. The greatest SQL Server compression rate is achieved when applying it to unicode types, or to shorter text values, especially if they're sorted in order. In your case you get no unicode compression. You get no text compression as the data isn't repeating in any way. You might actually end up with a larger result than to begin with, due to overhead.

Comment: @MarkS.Rasmussen I guess that could be possible. There is lots of repeating data (repeated words in an English sentence) for example, but I guess without looking at the compression SQL is using I can't really comment further.

Comment: The thing is, you'll _only_ save space if the repetition is in the beginning of the text - hence page compression being known as prefix compression. If you have two nearly identical strings where only the first symbol differs, they will not be compressed. For the same reason, sorting the data is extremely important so the prefix compression has optimal conditions to find similar prefixes on the same page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data is pushed off-row (which will likely happen on a `VARCHAR(8000)` column) then you don't get *any* compression on it. [Only the in-row data is compressed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280449.aspx):

> Because of their size, large-value data types are sometimes stored
>   separately from the normal row data on special purpose pages. Data
>   compression is not available for the data that is stored separately.

Comment: Thanks. I think you and Aaron are right. The data is probably off row and therefore not getting compressed at all. This leads to the questions: a) how do I detect if data is off-row, and b) how do I keep it in-row? 
I created a new question for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804558/how-to-keep-data-in-row-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

Page compression in SQL server uses prefix and dictionary methods to compress the data. It cannot (and you would not want it to) look at the entire data set to figure out the best compression. It can only look at a page of data at a time. The best results are achieved when each successive row in the page differs the least amount from the previous rows. The only way to accomplish this is cause SQL server to physically arrange the rows in each page so that they differ in the least possible degree from row to row. We can do this by creating a clustered index on the field, or set of fields, that guarantee that the physical arrangement of the data rows follow the least change from row to row model.

In the example you provided, a bunch of words in a single field, a suitable degree of compression may mot be achievable. This sounds like paragraphs of text, and will differ greatly, no matter how they are physically arranged.

The method that SQL server uses to compress data enables it to retrieve the contents of any row without having to decompress the entire page.

Comment: Right, and it would be impossible to create an index on the column shown in the example because the maximum key size is 900 bytes.

Comment: PAGE compression includes row compression. The text in each row is compressible by other standard methods (eg. ZIP).
Are we saying that the compression method SQL Server uses cannot compress a single VARCHAR(1234) cell which contains repeating text?

Comment: You could create a clustered index by using a subset of the large field.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by repeating text. SQL server does not go "all out" to compress the data. Remember, it must be able to get to , and retrieve, a single row via the compression methods it uses. If it did not, then the overhead of compression would bring the server to it's knees every time. MS went after the pattern found in most types of data found in multi-field tables.

Comment: I use another method to deal with compressed text. I use the \n Software IPWorks ZIP .net compression tools as a clr to SQL server. When I need to compress a text field, I feed the contents to the IPWorks zip control, and them store it as a varbinary(max) field.