# How to keep data in-row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to work out how to detect if data in a `VARCHAR(n)` column in SQL Server 2008 is being stored in-row or off-row.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Also, is there a way to keep the data in-row if we want it there?

Comment: What do you need to know exactly? It might not be the same for all rows. It is possible to determine this for specific rows using `DBCC PAGE` etc but if you just want to know aggregate sizes for in row and row overflow allocation units this is much simpler. You can also do a `SET STATISTICS IO ON;SELECT YourCol FROM YourTable` and look at lob logical reads.

Comment: I want to get SQL Compression working on this VARCHAR data, but I *think* that it is not working as the data is pushed out of row.

Comment: Can you add your table structure to the question?

Comment: @MartinSmith -- it's 
`INT (PK), VARCHAR(500)`

Comment: That should never be stored off row then. The row will never be big enough.

Comment: OK :( Looks like I'm never going to get this built in compression working then! Thanks @MartinSmith

Comment: @Mr.Flibble: What error are you getting?

Comment: @DaveMarkle - From earlier question [I think it just isn't compressing to the OP's expectations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790554/compressing-varchar-in-sql-2008-12-not-seeing-results)

Comment: @MartinSmith: Thanks.  Though I will grant it to him that he's definitely got a really small compression ratio there.  I guess it's time to buy an updated copy of Inside SQL Server for me (mine dates back to 2005)!

Comment: @DaveMarkle Yes - I'm not getting any errors regarding compression, but the compression is not compressing very much. I had though that perhaps it was because the data was being stored off-row and hence asked the question here. 
I really don't know what is causing the low/non-existent compression ratio. Right now it looks like I'll be rolling my own compression.
There's a question for that too :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797518/looking-for-a-dictionary-based-net-text-compression-library

Comment: I commented in the other thread. The problem here most likely isn't records being pushed off-row, but simply that the data does not compress with SQL Servers compression implementation.

Comment: the link can help you. I used it to solve my problem: https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/migrating-legacy-lob-data-types-to-current-ones-a-big-gotcha/

Answer (score 3):

To see if a value is in-row or off-row you can use [`DBCC PAGE`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2006/12/13/more-undocumented-fun_3a00_-dbcc-ind_2c00_-dbcc-page_2c00_-and-off_2d00_row-columns.aspx)

A way to force a `VARCHAR(N)` column to be in-row (not a `VARCHAR(MAX)` is to make it part of the clustered index key. This of course limits the length of the field to the maximum index key size of 900.

Comment: And may result in a somewhat deep b-tree depending on the length of said varchar(n)'s :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the "[large value types out of row](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189087.aspx)" option in SQL Server, if it's a VARCHAR(MAX)   column.  The documentation is worth reading, because setting the option does not immediately convert the data in the table.

```
sp_tableoption N'MyTable', 'large value types out of row', 'OFF'
```

Comment: I had tried this and got the error `Msg 2599, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_tableoption, Line 102
Cannot switch to in row text in table "Table_1".
`
But I think this command does not relate to VARCHAR, which is normally stored in-row. It is for `text` etc which usually out of row.

Comment: Ah, my command is only for VARCHAR(MAX) types.  I believe that VARCHAR(<fixed length>) is always stored in row.

Comment: @DaveMarkle - Not if that would make the row > 8060 bytes. Then it is stored in overflow pages.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Thanks... My cope of Kalen Delaney's book is around here somewhere... Those overflow pages aren't quite the same mechanism as LOB storage pages though, right?

Comment: @DaveMarkle - Yes they are different. IIRC the LOB pointer is to a tree structure as it needs to support content spanning multiple pages.

Answer (score -1):

to show how large a row can be before out of row storage is used:

```
    select OBJECTPROPERTY(Object_id('TableName'), 'TableTextInRowLimit')
```

to specify in row storage for a table:

```
    sp_tableoption 'TableName', 'text in row', 'ON'
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the 'text in row' option has been superceded by the the 'large value types out of row' option for VARCHAR(MAX) types.

Comment: I downvoted. Please take no offence. The command you refer to TEXT and other large data types which are normally out of row. They do not apply to VARCHAR(n) afaik.